# Taking an integrand outside a definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a rectangle $R_\epsilon=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid 1-\epsilon\leq x\leq 1+\epsilon,0\leq y\leq H\}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small, $H>0$  and $\epsilon$ depends on $H$.

> If $f$ is an analytic function on and inside the rectangle $R_\epsilon$ with no zeros or poles on the boundary of $R_\epsilon$ and $f(x+iH)$ is non zero for $1-\epsilon\leq x\leq1+\epsilon$ then prove that there exists an $M>0$ such that$$
>     \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}dx\leq   2\epsilon M\tag{1}$$
> where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part.

My try: Since $$
    \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}dx\leq  \left| 
  \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}dx\right|$$
So by triangle inequality
$$
    \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}dx\leq  
  \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}|\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}|dx $$
Take $$M=\max_{1-\epsilon\leq \sigma \leq 1+\epsilon} \left|\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}\right| $$
But note that $\epsilon$ is a function of $H$, so $\epsilon=\epsilon(H)$. So can we write equation (1) when $\epsilon$ depends on $H$? I mean can we write the following $$
    \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\Im \left\{ \log f(x+iH)\right\}d\sigma\leq M \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon} dx $$

Thank you.

Comment: The imaginary part of the logarithm is the argument. Assuming the principle branch, you can very lazily set $M=\pi/2$ and have done with it (I think)

Comment: I think one just needs to bound the argument. $M=\pi/2$ is wrong, but, if you use the principal branch of the logarithm, then definitely $M=\pi$ will bound the argument!

Comment: Sure, I think so. The maximum exists by continuity after all.

Comment: Since you're not claiming $M$ to be constant for all $H$, I don't think so. If $\varepsilon$ is a function of $H$ then $M$ is a function of $H$ (... but one may also take $M=\pi$, or $M=2\pi$, etc., depending on your logarithm branch)

Comment: @FShrike Yes but then since $M$ is a function of $H$ and is independent of $\sigma$ so we can take $M$ outside of the integral $\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}M dx$

Comment: $H$ and $\epsilon$ have meaning outside the integral. So does $M$. The only things you cannot bring outside the integral are those that depend on the variable $x$ of integration.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So we can bring $M$ outside the integral? Right?

Comment: Since $M$ does not depend on $x$, yes, it can be brought outside the integral.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. Please write as an answer. I will happily accept it