# Zeros of a non constant entire function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Consider a rectangle $D(\epsilon,T)=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\mid \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon,\ 0\leq y\leq T\}$ where $T>1$ and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small which depends on $T$.

> **Question** Let $f(z)$ be a non constant  entire function with no zeros on the real axis and satisfied $f(z)=f(1-z)$. Prove that there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $f(z)$ has no zeros on the boundary of the rectangle $D(\epsilon,T)$ whenever $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$. Please note that $\epsilon$ depends on $T$

My try: Let $T>1$ be not an ordinate of a zero of $f(z)$. We prove the above question by the method of contradiction. If possible let us suppose no such $\epsilon_0$ exists. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there must exist $\epsilon'$ with $0<\epsilon'<\epsilon$ such that the boundary of the rectangle $D(\epsilon',T)$ has atleast one zero of $f$.

In particular if we take $\epsilon_n=\epsilon_0^*/2^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0<\epsilon_0^*\leq 1$, then there exists $\epsilon_{n}'$ such that $0<\epsilon_n'<\epsilon_n=\epsilon_0^*/2^n$ such that the boundary of $D(\epsilon_n',T)$ has atleast one zero $z_n$ of $f$.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\{\epsilon_n'\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing and $\epsilon_n'\to 0^+$ (to see this choose $\epsilon_1'<\epsilon_1$ and then choose $\epsilon_2'<\epsilon_1'$ and $\epsilon_2'<\epsilon_0^*/2^2$. Next we choose $\epsilon_3'$ such that $\epsilon_3'<\epsilon_2'$ and $\epsilon_3'<\epsilon_0^*/2^3$
and we continue this process).

Now we consider a set $A=\{z_n\in \mathbb{C}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $z_n$ are those zeros of $f$ as we have chosen above. Now we can have two cases:

Case $1$: $A$ is an infinite set: Since $\epsilon_n=\epsilon_0^*/2^n$ so we have $\epsilon_0^*>\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2>\epsilon_3>...$ and hence all the zeros $z_n$ of set $A$ lie inside the rectangle $D(\epsilon_0^*,T)$ where $0<\epsilon_0^*\leq 1$ and clearly $D(\epsilon_0^*,T)$ is a bounded set. Hence we get that $A$ is also a bounded set.

So by the Bolzano--Weierstrass theorem, set $A$ has a limit point. Since $f$ is entire so by the Identity theorem since $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ is an infinite bounded subset of the zeros of $f$ and it has a limit point so $f$ must be identically zero which is a contradiction.

Case $2$: $A$ is a finite set:
In this case there are infinitely many $D(\epsilon_n',T)$ having common zeros of $f$, thereby forcing zeros to lie on the real axis (as only the real axis can be common in $D(\epsilon_n',T)$ ). This again contradicts the fact that $f$ has no zeros on the real axis.

Is the above solution correct? Do we need any modification? Please help me with this problem.

**Edit** We have proved provided that $T$ is not equal to an ordinate of a zero. But this restriction is now irrelevant, as may be seen by replacing $T$ by a larger value $T'$ (distinct from the ordinate of the zeros) and making $T'\to T+0$

Comment: The function $\sinh(2z-{1\over 4})$ vanishes on the real axis.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks a lot. So is my proof correct?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So even when $\epsilon$ depends on $T$ then also my proof works?

Comment: For $f(z)=z-({1\over 4}+2i)$ and $T=2$ the point ${1\over 4}+2i$ belongs to the boundary of the rectangle independently of $\varepsilon.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks. So how can we make some extra conditions so that $f$ has no zero on the boundary of the rectangle?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But what if $T>1$ is not an ordinate of zero of $f$?

Comment: The function $f$ may have countable many roots on the vertical half-line $x=1/4,\, y\ge 0.$ The value of $T$ should be different from the imaginary part of these roots.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So how to ensure that the function has no zeros on the boundary of the rectangle? Is my try correct or it needs some modifications?

Comment: The recent edit looks correct

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Thanks. But then how to remove the possibility of the counterexample $f(z)=z-(1/4+2i)$ and $T=2$?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Please write as an answer. I will with utmost respect accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $f$ does not vanish on the closed half-line $$E=\left\{z=x+iy\,:\,x={1\over 2}, y\ge 0\right\}$$ Fix $T>0$ and let  $$E_T=\left \{z=x+iy\,:\,x={1\over 2},\  0\le  y\le T\right \}$$
As the segment $E_T$
is compact (bounded and closed), there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $f$ does not vanish on
$$V_{\varepsilon_0}=\left \{z=x+iy\,:\, {1\over 2}-\varepsilon_0 \le x\le {1\over 2}+\varepsilon_0,\ 0\le  y\le T\right \}$$
*Indeed, assume by contradiction that $f$ vanishes in every $V_{1/n}$ say at $z_n.$ Then the sequence $z_n$ has an accumulation point $z_0$ in the segment $E_T.$ Thus $f\equiv 0$ which contradicts the assumptions.*

Hence $f$ does not vanish  on the boundary of any subrectangle of $V_{\varepsilon_0}.$

Assume now that $f$ has roots on the half-line $E.$ Let $T$ be chosen so that $f({1\over 2}+iT)\neq 0.$ The function $f$ may have finitely many roots in the segment $E_T,$ as the roots of a nonzero entire function cannot accumulate. Let $z_1,z_2,\ldots, z_n$ denote these roots (if there are any) and $m_1,m_2,\ldots, m_n$ denote their multiplicities. The function
$$g(z)=(z-z_1)^{-m_1}(z-z_2)^{-m_2}\ldots (z-z_n)^{-m_n}f(z)$$ is entire and does not vanish on $E_T.$ By the first part there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $g(z)$ does not vanish on $V_{\varepsilon_0}.$ Hence $$f(z)=(z-z_1)^{m_1}(z-z_2)^{m_2}\ldots (z-z_n)^{m_n}g(z)$$ does not vanish  on the boundary of any subrectangle of $V_{\varepsilon_0},$ as the only roots in $V_{\varepsilon_0}$ are located on the line $x={1\over 2}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There a few doubts. Why are we taking $T$ as fixed? It might be arbitrary?

Comment: It is a common expression. I fix  (arbitrary) $T$ as what follows is true for arbitrary fixed $T.$ For example $\varepsilon_0$ depends on $T.$ Formally I could denote $\varepsilon_0(T).$

Comment: Thanks. And $\epsilon$ is also depedent on $T$? Right?

Comment: So for the whole proof $T$ is fixed but $T$ it is fixed but arbitrary. Right?

Comment: I would say $\varepsilon$ is independent of $T$ but the range of $\varepsilon $  depends on $\varepsilon_0.$ The proof is valid for any value of $T$ such that $f(1/2+iT)\neq 0.$ The way it is presented requires fixing $T$ and then choosing $\varepsilon_0.$ If it was possible to get $\varepsilon_0$ good for any $T$ I wouldn't fix $T.$  But that is impossible as there are entire functions such that the roots tend to  the vertical half-line $E.$ Clearly the imaginary parts of these roots must tend to $+\infty.$

Comment: Okay. But if we change $T$ to $T'$ where $T'>T$ then $\epsilon$ will change. Right?

Comment: I would say $\varepsilon_0$ will change, i.e. the range of possible $\varepsilon >0$ will change. For $T$ the range of $\varepsilon$ is the interval $(0,\varepsilon_0(T)].$ For $T'>T$ this range is $(0,\varepsilon_0(T')]$  The intersection of these intervals give the range of $\varepsilon$ which are good for both $T$ and $T'.$ That's why I feel uneasy to say $\varepsilon$ changes. I prefer to say the range of possible values of $\varepsilon$ changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last question. How do we choose T so that $f(1/2+iT)$ is non zero?

Comment: The roots of entire function cannot accumulate. Therefore in any bounded set there may be only finitely many roots. In particular on any segment $x=1/2$ $0\le y\le n$ there are finitely many roots. Then for $T\le n$ we have to choose $T$ different from imaginary part of the roots (finitely many) in the segment described above.  $n$ is arbitrary natural number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My answer is correct with the recent edit?

Comment: In my opinion it is fine.

Comment: Thanks.Plus one and a check mark for your answer.

Comment: There is a similar question asked by my sister. Please see and answer if you wish to : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511837/upper-bound-of-a-definite-integral?noredirect=1#comment9475144_4511837